# java and sqlite for a complete beginner

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I'm writing a program which will need to create and make use of an sqlite database. What I need to do now is create the database and make sure all my classes can interact with it. I have looked online but alot of what i find contradicts itself. Can anyone explain simply how I would go about creating this database and connecting to it first of all?

Comment: Take a look at this : http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html

Comment: I've been through there am I just missing the part that has to do with using it in Java?

Comment: The Java tutorial won't refer to SQLLite specifically, but if you read it and actually understand it you'll realize that all you need to change is the database in which you create the tables, the driver class you need to include, and the connection string.   Everything else is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html).  It's how Java interacts with relational databases, including SQLLite.

SQLLite has lots of tutorials too, including [this one](http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/readme_sqlite_tutorial.html).

I have no idea what you found that contradicts itself.

Comment: Why yes, it is.  Or, worse, reading it and not understanding a bit of it.